# Как в Swift пробудить приложение в фоне при подключении к интернету, либо продолжить работу приложения в фоне в течение нескольких минут

Tags: swift

В чём суть: пользователь отправляет сообщение, которое должно попасть собеседнику через сервер. Если доступ к интернету есть, то оно отправляется сразу, если нет, то сохраняется в памяти, однако как только доступ к интернету появился, то в фоновом режиме всё должно отправиться на сервер (как это сделано в телеграмме, ватсаппе и т.д.).
Проблема возникает именно в пробуждении приложения в фоне при появлении интернета на айфонах. С андроидами вроде как должно быть проще, но если не сложно, то тоже подскажите как лучше сделать.
Либо сделать так, чтобы после сворачивания приложения, часть кода функционировало еще несколько минут